# R Counting related dates in an XTS (or data.frame) object

Tags: r, date, count, xts

in my studies I am analyzing historical wind speeds of meteorological stations (if the trend is increasing or decreasing etc.).
Now i have one value for each day.
I want to count the days, which are related to each other (for example 1958-03-18, 19, 20...). for every year i want to have a value how many (storm)days occured with more than 3 days in a row.

example:

```
1982-01-30  41.04
1982-02-02  45.72
1982-02-03  46.8
1982-02-04  41.04
1982-02-12  39.24
1982-02-17  53.28
1982-02-18  49.68
1982-02-19  40.32
1982-03-01  46.08
```

In February 1982 2 times is the situation (2,3,4) and (17,18,19).

Does anyone know how to count this and put it in a new table for further analyzing / plotting?

```
1982 23
1983 7
1984 11
.
.
.
```

At least just counting all days per year would help me,too.

Kind Regards
Sascha

Comment: What is the threshold you have used for a day to qualify as storm day?

Comment: Suppose you add a column with data as 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3.. to group adjacent dates. Then melt your table to collapse rows on minimum value in each group, finally count rows in melted table where this minimum value exceeds threshold. You will need to repeat these steps with columns as 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4.. and 1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4..

Comment: Our data base are hourly values per day. the max-value of the 24 values per day is used. After that we choose all days where this values is greater than 39 km/h.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple way to identify storm days (wind > 39 according to your comment) and dates with three successive storm days.

```
#create example data
fakedates <- as.Date("1982-01-01")+(1:730)
fakewind <- sample(1:80, length(fakedates), replace = TRUE)
dateyear <- format(fakedates, "%Y")

df <- data.frame("dates"=fakedates, "maxwind"=fakewind, "year"=dateyear)

#identify 'storm' days where max wind is >39
df$storm <- df$maxwind > 39  #identify storm days

# ensure original data is in chronological order, otherwise you would need to sort first
# e.g.  if(is.unsorted(original$dates), sort(original$dates, .... etc)

#identify 3-day storms - undetermined for last two days in the record
df$storm3 <-
  c(df$storm[1:(length(df$storm) - 2)] &
      df$storm[2:(length(df$storm) - 1)] &
      df$storm[3:(length(df$storm))], "unknown", "unknown")

#select all storm day records
dfs <- df[df$storm == TRUE, c(1:3)]

#select only dates of 3-day storms
dfs3 <- df[df$storm3== TRUE,(1:3)]
```

Your output would look something like this:

```
> head(dfs3)
        dates maxwind year
12 1982-01-13      57 1982
13 1982-01-14      47 1982
33 1982-02-03      65 1982
49 1982-02-19      79 1982
61 1982-03-03      49 1982
68 1982-03-10      55 1982
```

You can summarise by year and do whatever other analyses you require,  either with all storm days (dfs) or with three-day storm days only (dfs3).

When you are more famiiar with R, you could tackle the task in various other ways e.g. with package dplyr

Comment: Hi Jules,i am not very familiar with R but i try to use your suggestion. Thank you very much, it looks like i can use that :) With dplyr i want to check for example which days occur in all of the stations.